# ElasticSearch: Update multi fields in Script Java Plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I saw this snippet where **update_by_query** can update source directly

```
POST twitter/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.likes++",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

instead of using painless, I wrote a native script plugin in Java because of my complex business logic.

```
{
  "subtotal": 1000,
  "markup": 2,  
  "total": 2000,
  "items": [
      {
         "subtotal": 100,
         "markup": 2,
         "total": 200
      },
      {
         "subtotal": 500,
         "markup": 2,
         "total": 1000
      }
   ]
}
```

User can set markup value in the application. If user change markup to 3, **I want to update markup and total field including the ones in nested object.** (NOTE: I can't use painless because in my case, the logic is more complicated than just multiplies those fields. That's why I use Java)

```
// my plugin code
public Object run() {
     // change field value of "markup"
     // change field value of "total"   

   return true;
}
```

My Code is almost similar with https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/examples/nativescript/script/TFIDFScoreScript.java

I was trying with `source().put("markup", 3)` but I kept getting `NullPointerException`

ElasticSearch Version: 5.0.0

Thank you